# Selecting all x which are in y table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have table of users and cities. I want to get list of all cities that are in users collection so that I can acces to all cities id;

```
    public class City
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> AppUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Measurement> Measurements { get; set; }
}
   public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public override string Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<City> Cities { get; set; }
}
```

I have already tried

```
var cities = db.Cities.Where(c => c.AppUserID != null ); //and with .ToList()

var cities = from city in db.Cities
                     join user in db.Users
                     on city.AppUserID equals user.Cities
                     select city.ID;
```

but it doesn't work. 
Any solutions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `on city.AppUserID equals user.Cities` comparing `userid` with `cities` will surely never work

Comment: this model is not good...why has a user a relation to many cities? this would be better solved if you either make a 1:n realtion from user to city oder create a detaile table that makes the **n:m** to a **1:n** and a **n:1** relation

Comment: First you need to correct your question and ask exactly what you need, since you seem to be confused. I have answered exactly what you have asked along with the highlight of your point. All your other Linq queries that your have mentioned are completely incorrect and faulty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `c.AppUserID != null` does not work because the collection is empty, not `null`.

This will get you all cities wit non-empty `AppUserID` collections:

```
var cities = db.Cities.Where(c => c.AppUserID.Any() )
```

Comment: `Duplicate true`, but that's why I have suggested user can trim it further as per requirement. A simple `Distinct` would do

Comment: Solution does corrects OP's incorrect linq but does approach the issue from wrong direction, especially if we need to get the List of `cities` associated with the `user`. Solution to a great extent will depend on correct data being filled in the city collection, when the expected solution is  other way round